# "CUDA directory not found"

Tags: cuda, cudafy.net

I'm trying to install CUDAfy.NET for the first time but after installation I receive this error when I click "Run CUDA Test" on the CUDAfy viewer. I looked around but can only find one instance of this issue here: https://cudafy.codeplex.com/workitem/953.

I also get the same error when I try and perform the method `CudafyTranslator.Cudafy()`

What could be causing this? Do I need to point something to a directory?

Comment: As someone already suggested on the issue you created on cudafy.codeplex.com I'm quite sure you need to install the CUDA Toolkit available on the NVIDIA site.

Comment: Thanks rold. I installed the CUDA toolkit last night and restarted, no difference.

Comment: Ok, which version did you install ? For now Cudafy.Net only supports CUDA 6.5, and not 7.0.

Comment: I installed the latest version which is 7.0, go figure. Very annoying that they don't mention this... I'll trying installing 6.5 and report back.

Comment: Okay, after installing 6.0 I had to go into the "Environment Variables" settings in control panel and change the `PATH` variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin`, now it seems to be working. If you put your comment as an answer I'll be happy to tick it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current version (1.28) of Cudafy.Net only supports CUDA Toolkit 6.5. The default CUDA Toolkit to download on NVIDIA website is the version 7.0. Make sure you download and install version 6.5.

Note that CUDA Toolkit 7.0RC was released only 9 days (as of January 13th 2015) after Cudafy.Net 1.28 was released, so you can probably expect to be able to use 7.0 with the next version of Cudafy.Net (which isn't released yet, obviously).